# SharePoint 2010 Search issue

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, search-results

I'm having a problem with SP Search;
We have 1 App server(041), 2 WFE servers (039,040).
search is configured on APP server (041) as in the below:

[image]

I did crawling and search results are perfect, when i login as system account, i can see all results, but as a normal user, no result are shown! what do i need to do in order to make all users get search results? 
Any idea? what things i missed?

Comment: did you mean that the same web application is showing search results in one WFE and not the other? could you please ellaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you can access crawled content directly from this (039) server. You need to login to the server with the content access account and just open your crawled sites in the browser. If you won't be able to open sites, the search won't be able too.

Comment: I can access the server using the same account credentials and i am able to view the site, but no search results are there!!

Comment: guys, when i login as system account, i can see all results, but as a normal user, no result are shown! what do i need to do in order to make all users get search results?

Comment: does your content access account have "Full Read" permissions to the crawled application? Also your users should have permissions to the term they try to search for, or the security trimming will block showing them the results. Let me know if that's the issue.

Comment: How can i check the content access account's permissions?

Comment: In Central Administration -> Application Management -> Manage Web Applications -> Select the web application you want to crawl -> In the Ribbon, click User Policy. Your crawl account should be in the list with "Full Read" permission. If not, add it.